# How to access this, is this an object literal or?

Tags: javascript

My javascript looks like:

```
[{"user":{"property1":8,"property2":"asdfasdf"}}];
```

I tried:

```
alert(user.property1);
```

But nothing rendered, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to assign the object literal to a variable. You must do that in order to be able to reference it the way you seem to want. Note that `[]` indicates an array.

So you're almost there:

```
var myObj = [{"user":{"property1":8,"property2":"asdfasdf"}}];

alert(myObj[0].user.property1);
```

Your object literal creates an array, with an object that has a property named `user`. This `user` property itself is set to an object which has two properties - `property1` and `property2`.

Answer (score 4):

Your javascript is an array, I assume it's assigned to a variable?

```
var myArray = [{"user":{"property1":8,"property2":"asdfasdf"}}];
alert(myArray[0].user.property1);
```

Comment: bad assumption, I knew I was missing something!